# Matplotlib Axes Transformation invalid after saving figure with no padding

Tags: python, matplotlib, padding, transformation

I have a matplotlib figure with a scatterplot on the axes. I also have a data coordinate and it's pixel value through ax.transData.tranform(). However, when the figure is saved with no padding, then the pixel value means nothing (it only corresponds correctly when the figure is saved with no adjustments to padding)

E.g. when ax.transData() works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(0, 10)
ys = np.arange(0, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
fig.tight_layout()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.scatter(xs, ys)
fig.savefig('test.png')

data_coord = 0, 0
pixel_coord = ax.transData.transform(data_coord)
```

If you check the pixel coordinate of 0, 0  you will see it to be correct on 'test.png'.

E.g. when ax.transData() doesn't work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(0, 10)
ys = np.arange(0, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
fig.tight_layout()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.scatter(xs, ys)
fig.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)

data_coord = 0, 0
pixel_coord = ax.transData.transform(data_coord)
```

pixel_coord does not fall on point (0, 0) on test.png.

Possible solutions:
Since the removal of padding happens after we have finished with our axes then my best thought would be if you could specify the no padding before the saving the figure but haven't found any documentation on that. I feel like there must be an easy solution to this hidden somewhere. I just need the pixel coordinate to agree with the data coordinate on the figure with no padding.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It’s not at al clear what you are trying to accomplish.   It yes, if you save with a different geometry (bbox_inches=tighht) the pre-save geometry will not apply.

Comment: I want the pixel coordinate to correspond to the data coordinate on the saved figure with no padding. The image and the pixel coordinate will be passed to another module. That is all.